# Как тестировать объекты со сцены юнити?

Tags: unity3d, юнит-тесты

Все юнит тесты обычно находятся в папке Editor и не наследуют от MonoBehaviour. Как протестировать элемент со сцены в юнит тесте или проще говоря как добавить элемент сцены в юнит тест?
P.S. Как я понимаю искать элементы с помощью Find, FindGameObjectWithTag и т.д. не совсем правильно.

Comment: Кто то знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один из способов, как мне кажется, это просто создать новый пустой объект в тестируемом методе, добавив нужный компонент или инстанциировать нужный префаб и запустить тест? Пример:

```
GameObject go = new GameObject();
go.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviour>();

// do smth...
```

---

**Но...**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Unity Test Tools](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13802) - пакет, с помощью которого можно протестировать объекты на сцене.

Например к объекту прикрепляется компонент [Assertion Component](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/wiki/AssertionComponent) (он есессн будет Monobehaviour):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нём можно задать любые параметры, которые душе угодно: объект тестирования, параметры тестировани, с чем сравнивать, сколько должен длиться тест, в какой момент времени проверять (Start, Update, OnTriggerEnter и прочее) и многое другое.

Документацию о нем можно почитать их доки:

[bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/wiki/Home](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/wiki/Home)

Ознакомиться можно также посмотрев небольшое видео в обучающих материалах на самом сайте Unity:

https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/production/unity-test-tools.

Там описан пример как с `Unit test` так и `Integration test`.